# SQL select string that doesn't contain Y but contains X

Tags: sql, regex, select, sql-like

I'm attempting to select all of the instances where this database field has a string but does not contain a specific value.

Example: I'm trying to select every instance of "red chair" where "red chair" is not proceeded by "big". If I were to run that query in the following table, I'd only get the row with the ID of 2 back:

```
+----------+--------------+---------+
| ID       |        content         | 
+----------+------------------------+
| 1        | The big red chair      |
| 2        | I have a red chair     |
| 3        | I have a big chair     |
+----------+------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You wouldn't get row 3 back either since it doesn't contain the text "RED CHAIR".

Comment: Some engines are case insensitive by default, others have options (or operators) to perform this comparison in a case-insensitive manor.  In any event, I doubt it's the case-sensitivity that Katzumi is wrestling with.

Comment: -1 Title and question are contradictory. Also, example and text are contradictory (upper case?). Please fix.

Comment: Updated the question title to match the response and removed the upper case. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use:

`LIKE '%red chair%' AND NOT LIKE '%big%'`

**edit**: Fixed LIKE matching strings

Comment: Or to even be a little more precise: LIKE '%red chair' AND NOT LIKE 'big red%'

Comment: Unfortunately, this will still select row 1.  It may also have problems with selecting row 2, depending on how the OP's flavor of SQL handles end-of-row blank characters.  This _is_ along the right lines - you'll need to add the '%' character on _both_ sides of _both_ strings.

Comment: This answers (incorrectly) the title of the question, but the actual question does not really match the title.

Comment: Larry, that was my main problem in finding a solution. How would you title this help request? I will attempt to edit, it they allow me.

Answer (score 4):

This will get what you want, assuming the phrase "red chair" occurs only once in `content`.  If it can appear more than once ('The red chair is a big red chair'), what result do you want?

```
SELECT * FROM Furniture 
  WHERE content LIKE '%red chair%' AND content NOT LIKE '%big red chair%'
```

Comment: I eventually want to insert the word "small" in front of the instance where RED CHAIR is not preceded by the word big. Therefore, if there is more than one instance in the content - I'd like those replaced too.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE content like '%red chair%'
AND content not like '%big red chair%'
```

It's not going to be fast though!

Answer (score 0):

> Select string that STARTS WITH X and DOES NOT CONTAIN X

```
WITH T 
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('xenophilia'), 
                     ('xbox'), 
                     ('regex')
             ) AS T (c)
     )
SELECT * 
  FROM T
 WHERE c LIKE 'x%'
       AND c NOT LIKE '_%x%';
```